# Stopping unsolicited emails in particular Viagra & Cialis

Tags: email

I would like to ask if anyone knows a way for me to stop receiving unsolicited (aka unpleasant) mail into my junk mailbox.

I am particularly referring to 'requests' for me to purchase 'Viagra or Cialis'. I am a 62-year-old woman and don't want this sort of thing landing into my junk box. I also get some pretty explicit emails for women. (My name can be either female or male.) Any form of advice would be greatly appreciated. I look forward to refining some helpful suggestions.

Comment: Can you please mention which email service do you use (and email client, if any?)

Comment: Unfourtunately, there is likely little you can do to stop them, as the operation to send them to you is already illegal, so traditional options just don't exist. If the mail is already going to Junk, then what more do you need?

Comment: Use an email that has not been shared by anyone.  Even if you do that most spam is automatically generated and even if you have never used the addressed, and it has never been sent email, these generators will still send you spam.  Because it costs nothing. to try every single combination. and send it an email.

Comment: Change your e-mail with a better spam filter (e.g. gmail) and don't share your e-mail address anywhere on the internet.

Comment: @Sathya. Hello back to you Sathya. Thanks for your response. Apologies for delayed reply back. I am using Outlook and the email address I have is sup[plied (free!) by Hotmail. Dose that help you to help me stop these unsolicited mails I continually receive?

Comment: @Sathya I  thought I had set this but not showing me that it was in fact set. Hello Sathya, thank you for your response;  apologies for the delayed reply back to you. I am using Outlook & the email address I have is  Hotmail (free!) . Will this help you to assist me in getting rid of & stopping these horrid emails? Hope so! Look forward to hearing back from you. Best wishes Corinne

Answer (score 1):

Many email clients allow you to discard messages based on keywords in the subject and body. If you do not expect to receive legitimate messages which contain these words, filtering out the matches should be easy to set up.  Your question does not mention any particular software or platform so I hope you can find instructions for your particular circumstances by googling for terms like "Outlook filter keyword" (assuming you are an Outlook user for this example).

However, many senders of unsolicited bulk email use various evasion techniques to avoid this sort of simple filter. If you cannot filter on keywords, you will probably want to explore installing a separate spam filter, ideally on the server where your mail is delivered. Many mailbox providers offer server-side spam filtering with versatile and complex content analysis to identify and block unsolicited messages even when they contain various kinds of obfuscations (and often spotting them *because* they use particular obfuscation techniques).

The absolutely best defense against spam is to not publish your email address in the open in the first place.  If the cat is already out of the bag, so to speak, perhaps you can at least create a new, separate email address to use with close acquaintances, and avoid giving it out to strangers or putting it on a web page anywhere. You can still keep your old email address active, perhaps with stronger spam filters enabled, and/or only fetching and reading the messages it receives more rarely than your new primary, protected address.

Some of us have vanity domain names, which means we can create new email addresses for different uses whenever we like.  I would estimate that I create a few dozen new email addresses every week, and turn off or expire the ones which start to receive spam or otherwise stop being useful.